# Starting Android Service on Boot

Tags: android, android-service, bootcompleted, system-services

I have to develop an Android App that starts a service on boot. I have the privilege of creating even a new service in framework for it. But before that I have two question so this might be possible without going to framework.

1. Can an app (service only) signed with system keys be launched without an app launcher and start on boot without any activity ?
2. This is really another way of asking the first question : Can an app signed with system keys start for the very first time with BOOT COMPLETED broadcast intent ? I am aware that this is not possible for apps in user app space

Further documentation on the topic can be found [here](https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html)

Comment: Don't understand your question! You can always start a service on the BootComplete intent.

Comment: No. The application can be started from boot completed broadcast from the second time onwards but the first time user has to manually start the app from app launcher. The apps are in a stopped state and they cannot even receive any broadcast until they are are started for the first time by clicking on the app

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can you point to Documentation that states so?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/13/boot-completed-regression-confirmed.html

Comment: And I have tested it myself also

Comment: Does the question sound more meaningful now ?

Comment: Much better. I would edit the question, and add the link there.